# parameterize DB connection during Build & deployment in Visual Studio Online VSO with .net project

Tags: entity-framework, azure, msbuild, azure-devops

I have a .Net 4.5 project (it will soon be upgraded to 4.6) that talks to a database. Right now I have different databases (dev test production) parameterized in my web.config file that looks like this

```
 <add name="DevConnection" connectionString="blah...." />
 <add name="TestConnection" connectionString="blah ... test" />
 <add name="ProductionConnection" connectionString="blah... production" />
```

The way I switch this before I deploy Azure (PaaS or IaaS) is I change the following

```
 public DBContext(): base("DevConnection") // this one is our azure Dev DB
  {

  }
```

in my DbContext file.

**Is there a way I could parameterize that DevConnection on the right so when I queue up a build in Visual Studio Online aka VSTS or Visual Studio Team Services so it can switch the database to match the environment I am deploying to?** Any insight on preferred ways to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Web.Config Transformation, refer to following links for detail:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx

Comment: web.config transformations are nice but work only as long as you are OK with having different builds for different environments. For each change in the environments or new environment you'll need to rebuild the solutions. If you want to also use release management for deployment web.config transformations don't really fit into this scenario.

Comment: how would i specify which web.XXXX.config to hit during a build in VSTS?

Comment: It depends on the build configuration. For example, if you queue a build with "Debug" configuration, then web.debug.config will be applied during the build.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT oh I must have missed it I can queue a build with debug or release when I select? I must have just clicked go and never noticed

Comment: @FrankVisaggio Yes, by changing the value of "BuildConfiguration" variable.

Comment: Thanks for all your posts on VSTS and formerly VSO very useful content

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the new web based build system, you can build the .NET project to a WebDeploy package using the [Visual Studio Build step](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613727) and with a second [Azure Web App Deployment step](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/steps/deploy/azure-web-app-deployment) deploy the WebDeploy to Azure. Instead of having different connection strings you'll pass different parameters to the WebDeploy deployment step to set the connection string in the `web.config` accordingly.

You can also use the new [release management](http://aka.ms/rmhelp), which is currently in preview, to deploy the web deploy to different environments.

Comment: do you happen to know what i would pass in the MSBuild Arguments to change the connection string in my web.config file?  Unfortunately I am not deploying to azure web apps im deploying to IaaS classic vms so my deployment is a bit more convoluted than that step which may complicate things.

Comment: The newly created [Release Management Utility Tasks Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemname=ms-devlabs.utilitytasks) contains a task to tokenize environment specific configuration which might work for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single build and then use Release Management to deploy to different environments.

You can use the Tokenizer task to change the DB config string depending upon the environment you are deploying to. The task is not there in VSO by default and the instructions to upload the same are in the below link.

[tokenization VSTS task (github repo)](https://github.com/TotalALM/VSTS-Tasks/tree/master/Tasks/Tokenization)